# Server 2008 R2 Secondary Domain Controller - Accidentally Disabled Network Adapter

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have a server at a remote office running Server 2008 R2. This server is a local domain controller for that office. I was having issues with Active Directory not replicating and I disabled the network adapter by accident. Now I am unable to login to the machine and my local user at the site cannot login with domain admin credentials. As this is a domain controller I am unable to login as a local user.

Is there a way to enable the network adapter by modifying a file within windows if I boot via Linux or something?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/31d91a28-ed74-4a33-be15-23b9ebce4735/windows-server-2008-repairrestore?forum=winservergen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone else dumb enough to make this mistake, here's what worked for me.

Boot to Linux, and turn the adapter back on via Windows registry.